# How to use typoscript (Typo3 ver 6.2.11) to parse the following HTML result?

Tags: html-parsing, typo3, typoscript

I need the result that is parsed as following snipit of code:

```
<div class="my-content" id="d{uid}">
<h1>{header}<span class="subtitle">{subheader}</span></h1>
<p>{bodytext}</p>
</div>
```

Where {x} is the corresponding field from tt_content table. The typoscript tutorials were too vague for me to understand. A sample code or reference site to implement similar problem (with nested column values) would highly be appreciated.

Comment: Looks almost like a `Fluid` template to me. Therefore use a `CONTENT` object the select the rows and a `FLUIDTEMPLATE` to render the `CONTENT`. Examples can be found plenty.

Comment: @pgampe: I have the following settings:
`code`
10 = TEXT  
 10 {
     required = 1
  wrap = <h1 class="headings"> | </h1>
     stdWrap.field = header
 }

20 = TEXT
 20 {
     required = 1
     wrap = <p class="paragraph"> | </p>
     stdWrap.field = bodytext
        parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
 }
`code`
This works fine for each column in single element. But I need to add subheading inside the H1 tag (nested). How to achieve this, any suggestions?

Comment: Please take a look at the template provided by `CSS Styled Content`. It has examples how to archive this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following and it worked as desired. I'll post it such that it might help others as well or for my own future reference :)

```
10 = TEXT
10 {
    required = 1
    wrap = <div class="my-content" id="d|">
    stdWrap.field = uid
}

20 = TEXT
20 {
    required = 1
    wrap = <h1>|
    stdWrap.field = header
}

30 = TEXT
30 {
    required = 1
    wrap = <span class="subtitle">|</span></h1>
    stdWrap.field = subheader
} 

40 = TEXT
40 {
    required = 1
    wrap = <p>|</p></div>
    stdWrap.field = bodytext
    parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE
}
```